# Comparing values in a dataframe by similarity percentage

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logic, similarity

I am trying to find a way to compare the values of the same dataframe. There is a column called urlsCleaned. It has URLs in it and I want to make it where if two URLs in two separate rows have matching values of at least 85% and have the exact same username in their rows I will then build an edge between those two URL nodes. I am not looking for help to make the graph but logically how do I compare values in the same dataframe? I want to be able to change the similarity between the URLs to find the percentages that work best for my use case.

```py
import csv
import twint
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import nest_asyncio
import networkx as nx
import re

nest_asyncio.apply()

NWO_data = pd.read_csv("TwitterLinksNWO.csv")
NWO_data["urlsCleaned"] = NWO_data["urls"]
NWO_data["urlsCleaned"] = NWO_data["urlsCleaned"].str.replace('wrestling', '4444')
NWO_data["urlsCleaned"] = NWO_data["urlsCleaned"].str.replace('aarp.org', '4444')

NWO_data = NWO_data[~NWO_data.urlsCleaned.str.contains("4444")]
```

The follow information is to understand how the dataframe is set up. These are examples of two of the rows in the dataframe and the heading names of the columns.

| username | name | tweet | language | mentions | urls | replies_count | retweets_count | likes_count | hashtags | link | retweet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tristan_dupree | Tristan du Pree | My highlight of 2016? Definitively the NWO Vid... | en | [] | ['https://twitter.com/i/moments/81329125861769... | 0 | 11 | 23 | ['higgsztoa'] | https://twitter.com/Tristan_duPree/status/8147... | False |
| bobbyxtreme | BOBBY XTREME | Get a personal video message from @RealKevinNa... | en | [{'screen_name': 'realkevinnash', 'name': 'kev... | ['http://CelebVM.com/KevinNash'] | 1 | 11 | 34 | ['nwo', 'wwe', 'wcw', 'tna', 'ecw', 'magicmike... | https://twitter.com/BOBBYXTREME/status/8135537... | False |

How would I go about coding this?